# ESLint Rule: Break nested JSX Elements into Multi Lines

Tags: reactjs, eslint

I'd like to configure my ESLint to automatically style my JSX Elements. Basically it should convert this:

```
<Link to={'operations'}><Button variant={'contained'}><i>Çalışmalar</i></Button></Link>
```

to this

```
<Link to={'groups'}>
  <Button variant={'contained'}>
    <i>Gruplar</i>
  </Button>
</Link>
```

I just can't seem to find the correct ESLint rule for it.

I have tried some rules like *react/jsx-newline*, but they are not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achive this with [prettier](https://prettier.io) .

install the extension in your VSCode then see [here](https://www.alphr.com/use-prettier-vs-code/) how to setup ESLINT and PRETTIER in React app

Comment: I know I can do it with prettier but I want to use ESLint only.

Comment: You cannot do it with Eslint it is not used for that

Comment: I felt that it should have been possible but thanks for your answer.